Is it plausible that helicopters are safer than cars?
For some reason there is a lot of talk on helicopter safety online at the moment, and one fact that keeps coming up is "helicopters are safer than cars", supported by this article "Are helicopters safe? How they stack up against planes, cars and trains".  It notes the problem that "We know the number of flight hours for airline flights and helicopter flights. We know the number of passenger miles traveled for airline flights, rail travel and (roughly) car travel." and introduces the death index, described as:

how much more likely you are to die, roughly, by traveling a similar distance in the U.S. on each mode of transportation, with airlines as the baseline. The "death index" is the number of times more likely you are to die.

This gives value of 1 for airlines (by definition), driving or riding in a car/SUV as 453.6 and Non-scheduled helicopter flights as 63.0.
A different calculation is done by the "turbulence forecast tool" company turbli which uses DOT figures (confirmed correct for cars fatalities and miles).  This gives a rate of 120 fatalities per billion passenger hours for cars, 296 for trucks and 0.88 for commercial plane, a ratio of 136 - 336, compared to the death index (based on miles) of 453.6.  This seems pretty close, and considering the speed could be counted differently depending when one "starts the watch" in the airport.
There is an article in the LA Times about the fatal accident rate particularly of the Robinson R44, and quotes a rate of 1.6 deadly accidents per 100,000 hours flown, "50% higher than any other of the dozen most common civilian models".  This is 16,000 per billion hours, and "any of the other most common civilian models" are 12,000, or exactly 100 times that of cars.  This is too different to be put down to the speed difference and how you could airport time.
Are calculations that make helicopter travel safer than cars, and only 2 orders of magnitude more dangerous than commercial air travel, credible?

Considering how heavily regulated, thoroughly trained and constantly retrained & reevaluated pilots are vs the general populace of drivers (who, in America, are generally tested once when they first get their driver's license and never tested again), it shouldn't be surprising that air travel of any sort is significantly safer than ground travel.

Your DOT numbers give you 100X greater risk in "common civilian model" helos than cars; start with that.  It seems like you're questioning the conclusion of the first article, which is based on entirely opaque data and an unknown "non-scheduled" helo flights. Is that like Part 135 helos, or all General Aviation helo flights too? Until we can see The Points Guy's methodology, there's nothing to compare to the NTSB data except his conclusion. I'm unclear what answer might be possible get here beyond what is already given from the NTSB data.

To be clear, the DOT/NTSB numbers do not have helicopter data, I have only confirmed car fatalities/mile in that.  The helicopter crash rate came from the LA times, and it is so different I thought I must be missing something.

The R-44 is a pretty light helo, with a fair number being used by low-time pilots with minimal supervision.  IF the term "non-scheduled" does in fact refer to Part 135 helo operations, then those are looking at data for larger aircraft with more supervision, higher pilot experience levels, and more regulated maintenance and operations. So it wouldn't be surprising that Part 135 accident numbers are well below R-44 and Part 91 helo numbers.  Enough to get below automobile fatality rates? Possible, but I'd have my doubts.

Why do you think they are not credible?

@DJClayworth They cannot both be credible, as they are a factor of 100 different.

This is almost certainly going to be about untangling the statistics, and not about aviation.

There was a an article in FLYING magazine many years ago where a researcher wanted to know the safest single engine aircraft, fixed wing or rotary wing, based on a probability of death of one or more occupants. You would think the 172 would come out on top, but the single engine aircraft with the lowest risk of death was the Bell 206 helicopter. A significant factor was helicopters generally crash from a hover, where there is little energy, and the disintegrating rotor bits are generally heading away from the cabin.

The Robinson R-22 and R-44 helicopters are known to have very very high accident numbers, mostly because they are operated by amateur pilots with considerably less experience than prof. helicopter pilots, due to their comparatively cheap acquisition and operation costs. So much so, that these two helicopter types are a main driver (almost 50%) of all fatal accidents in non-commerical operation. See Page 187 of the EASA Safety Review

The Points Guy article title has a disconnect with the article body, but that's typical. The title asks if helicopters are "safe", but this should include injuries not just fatalities. I always hear people say, "But in a car crash you might survive, in an airplane crash everyone dies". Which of course is not true, but I then say "I'm glad you brought up injuries" as besides the 40,000 annual deaths in the U.S. from auto accidents, over 1 million are injured enough to require medical attention. And many of these are life changing injuries. Injury numbers adds another dimension to the question.
